# How do I reveal "hidden" image noise

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, imagemagick, jpeg, preview.app

Computer images can hide compression noise that's barely noticeable when looking directly at it, but if you tilt your laptop screen you see the noise, eg. the edges around the cans in [this image](https://m0.joe.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/01083533/1.jpg).

**Main question**: How can I make noise like this become blindingly obvious when looking *directly* at the screen? What filters should I run? (I use ImageMagick, Photoshop and macOS Preview).

Side questions, if anyone can shed more light on this phenomenon:

1. What is the technical explanation of why image noise like this is "revealed" when changing the viewing angle of the screen. Is this the same for all screen types (plasma, LED, OLED, etc.)?
2. This kind of noise is a common mistake. A person who doesn't know better saves an image with high compression and thinks to himself, "This looks OK", and forgets to test the image under non-ideal circumstances (ie. a tilted screen, different calibration, etc.). Does Photoshop et. al. have functionality to warn about almost-invisible noise, since it's such an easy mistake?

Comment: What noise I see looks like discretisation. You need to determine whether the noise is in the image, or is cause by scaling to the screen dimensions. If you display in 1:1, you should be able to pan around and see the defects in the image itself.

Comment: @AFH: I know you can search for them when zooming, tilting your screen, squinting your eyes, etc. The question is how image filters can help you *not* having to do those things. I had a go with Photoshop Elements, and turning brightness to a minimum (-150) actually revealed compression damage very well! However, ImageMagick did not produce the same effect (`convert image.jpg -brightness-contrast -50x0`). And Preview has no Brightness control at all.

Comment: It might all depend on your screen... I'm not seeing anything in particular even at extreme angles, though most laptops I've ever seen [I don't use lappies for this reason amongst others] have a massive amount of 'image collapse' if you're not square to them.

Comment: @Tetsujin: This example is not very bad. I'll post worse ones if I come across them.

Comment: Have you played with the curves? I expect they will reveal it nicely...

Comment: @Attie: Found "Adjust Colour Curves" in Photoshop Elements. Using the "Solarise" preset revealed damages quite well!

Answer (score 0):

LCD screens use polarized light, meaning light emits from each pixel in a thin line.  So certain angles are optimum and if you start to look away from the optimum angle, the brightness and contrast of the image will change - but not evenly - and you can notice things you did not before.

This [physics.stackexchange.com answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/155391/what-happens-if-you-remove-the-polarization-filter-from-a-computer-monitor) explains and points to a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bf3547WB5qs) that shows exactly what's happening.

LED and plasma technologies are not polarized so they do not exhibit the phenomenom.

> Since this is such a common mistake, do image apps have functionality to help/warn the user about such noise, or is it left to the competence (and screen tilting) of the user?

Any lossy compression will damage the image and create artifacts, and various types of compression work better for various types of images.  You should avoid using JPEG for images that consist of high-contrast line-based drawings, for example.  Many programs that let you create JPEGs allow you to set the quality level, experimenting with different quality levels may be needed.

If you invert all colors of the processed image (easily done with a simple program like Irfanview), typically any artifacts become extremely obvious.

Comment: "Brightness and contrast of the image will change - but not evenly": Exactly. Because JPEG compression is based on what it thinks the eye will ignore under ideal circumstances, a change in circumstances (eg. brightness and contrast) will reveal excessive optimisations. I tried inverting the image in Photoshop Elements, but this actually revealed no artefacts at all. How come we get different results?

Comment: Try `gamma correction` and set it to a low value. In Irfanview you can find that option under `Image/color corrections`.

Answer (score 0):

> Main question: How can I make noise like this become blindingly obvious when looking directly at the screen? What filters should I run? (I use ImageMagick, Photoshop and macOS Preview).

Assuming you have access to the original image in a file that has not had the lossy compression applied (i.e. not saved as JPG):
Take the difference of the images (e.g. load as layers in gimp or Ps, play with layer modes) and then make the larger differences stand out (e.g. Auto levels?).

Comment: Good suggestion, but in most cases I don't have the original image. You just get an image that has this noise, and you want to be notified about it. You want your image editor to say "You're about to save an image that has this crappy compression noise that's almost invisible. Look! Here it is..." and then reveal it clearly to you.

Comment: JPG (or any other format using a lossy compression) is more similar to "printing" than being a viable option for saving data backups (e.g. for later processing). To be able to detect the anomalies you need to somehow "optimize" the image and do the comparison to that data as described above.